# Is padding-bottom relative to element's width?

Tags: css, responsive-design, aspect-ratio

Padding-bottom must be relative to element's width but i tested in last version of Chrome and Firefox and padding-bottom is relative to parent's width.

I need a element relative to element's width but it doesn't work:

```css
width: 200px;
padding-bottom: 50%; /* must be 100px  */
height: 0;
```

See example: http://dabblet.com/gist/6898263

What can i do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, in the [`padding` properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-padding-bottom), percentages are relative to the width of the [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#x0), which is here probably the `body` element or a `div` element with no width set, so it occupies the available width.

If you wrap the element in a `div` container and set the desired width on the container, then you can use a percentage as intended.

Answer (score 1):

There is no connection between `width` and `padding` properties. However, there is a third thing that they both rely on. It's `em` unit ([documentation](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#em-unit)). `Em` unit can be used to define all measurable properties (like width, border-width etc.) and it depends on font-size (which should be in that case defined in `px`).

You can try **this simple hack**:

```
font-size: 200px;
width: 1em;
padding-bottom: 0.5em;
```

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wgzrn/.

In your example you used another `div` inside with desired `font-size` defined to `24px` so `200px` font-size in the parent won't be a problem here.

My solution is not much elegant but I don't know any other.

Comment: This does not address the question. It suggests a different approach to an assumed underlying problem.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, that's true. Notice a `hack` keyword.

Comment: Is useful but the correct is use containers with div and child with width 100% and padding-bottom relative to parent's width. Even so i am grateful to know these hack.

Answer (score 0):

Why you add the padding and the background color to the wrapped div? If I change the css on your gist with the following css, I have a 100px padding. Here the code:

```
div.aspect-ratio {
  width: 200px;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
}

div.aspect-ratio > div {
  padding-bottom: 50%; /* must be 100px  */
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Because is a example. In my real project the width is 100% but it has a max-width. I can use multiple divs like your example: http://dabblet.com/gist/6898777 and works. Thanks.